# Handle already-liked pictures in SQL-Database efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, records

I'd like to check; if a user has already liked a picture via MySQL. 
I know that it would be easy to make a table with the entities like:

```
id
userFK
picturesFK
```

which goes one additional record each time, a user likes a picture.

But the table would be huge

for example 1000 users like 1000 posts, the table already has 1 million entries.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this check?

Comment: It's okay if somebody downvotes the question. But please say, why you've downvoted.

Comment: Somwehat off topic, but I can't think of a way of doing it in MySQL, but in dbs that support arrays, Postgres, MongoDB, for example, you can do this by embedding, rather than by having a many to many join table as you would have to do it here. Whether the performance would improve, I can't tell you.

Comment: your requirements look similar to social network. for such apps nosql databases are preferred. I think casandra or mongodb are the names you should look for.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, the fact that the user has liked the picture has to be stored somewhere, so no, I don't think there is a way around the fact that if 1000 users like 1000 pictures each, you will have 1 million records *somewhere*.

However, you could optimize this by not having an `id` column (which would presumably be the primary key).  Normally I would not recommend creating a table without a primary key, so you would instead want to make the entire table the primary key, i.e., with `PRIMARY KEY (userFK, picturesFK)`.  This has some disadvantages but it makes the table 1/3 smaller.